# android java convert timestamp 2012-11-13T18:38:30Z to time ago

Tags: java, android, timestamp

When I call a youtube API, it returns the following timestamp:

```
2012-11-13T18:38:30Z
```

I need to calculate 'time ago' based on current time and the above time stamp.
So, using the timestamp above, and current time, I should get something like 6 days ago, etc.

I need to convert it in android, so any android or java answer can help.

There seems to be a function that calculates time ago, but you need to first convert the 2012-11-13T18:38:30Z to millisecond or seconds, or whatever

and my question is, in java, how do you convert 2012-11-13T18:38:30Z to something else that can give me seconds, days, or whatever.

Comment: You question is not very clear. Could you rephrase it? What do you mean by converting to seconds? Please take some time to edit and make the question lucid. Thanks.

Comment: i just did, please let me know if it is clear to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this pattern for parsing your timestamp.

`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
java.util.Date parsedTimeStamp = format.parse("2012-11-13T18:38:30Z");
long videoTime = parsedTimeStamp.getTime();
```

I have told you the first part, and unfortunately, I am low on time, so you are on your own for the next steps: (I will add code later.)
`videoTime` will give you time in milliseconds of the video. You can get current time using 
`long systemTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000`. <s>Subtract these two, and convert the result of the subtraction to get the difference.</s>

```
Calender c1 = Calender.getInstanec().setTime(new Date(videoTime));
Calender c2 = Calender.getInstanec().setTime(new Date(systemTime));
```

Create two calenders using this date, and using Calender methods, you find difference between dates in terms of days and months.

Comment: Thanks..but java.util.Date parsedTimeStamp = format.parse("2012-11-13T18:38:30Z"); throws an exception, saying it is unparseable date

Comment: I just searched SO, it has been answered before. Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleDateFormat class to create Date object and then getTime() to get it in milliseconds.

Try Google, you will get lots of examples.

Comment: no, i mean converting this string "2012-11-13T18:38:30Z" to whatever, as long as i can extract ms

Answer (score 0):

You mean Conversion from Date to Long?

This might help

http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-conversion/DateToLong.shtml

Comment: No, the example doesn't help, i have been seaching for a while, none of them work, i am converting this specific string 2012-11-13T18:38:30Z to whatever value as long as i can extract milli second value

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert that to **milliseconds** it's only specified to the **second**.